# Is there a thing named a "spiral plane" which is a plane but it's spiral?

Tags: infinity, plane-curves

[image: approximate representation for spiral plane extending for infinity]
Hello, I'm wondering if there is such thing like this. Is there a plane which is not flat but spiral and extending for infinity? I have drawn a representation for what I mean but it's not thorough it's getting narrower inside it and getting further apart from the outside and it extends for infinity and extends from either sides? do you understand me?

Comment: Are you asking for the equation of such a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (3 dimensional space)?  Are you asking for the name of such a spiral plane?  It's properties?  I'm not sure I'm clear on what the question is.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about the name of that surface.

Comment: Also, I want to know the equation of the shape ..

Comment: To be clear, your shape has both straight lines in $\Bbb R^3$ as well as spirals?

Comment: In other words, this shape might be badly approximated as a cylinder?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you ..

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to call such an object a "cylinder." Begin with a spiral in the plane, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral , then put that in $\mathbb R^3$ by doing the same thing for every $z$ value.

Comment: That is not the normal meaning of the word "cylinder"! It is not even the set-theoretic meaning of "cylinder of a logarithmic spiral with respect to $A$" for some $A$, because if $A = \mathbb R$, then the logarithmic spiral is not a subset of $A$; and if $A = \mathbb R^2$, then the cylinder is a subset of $\mathbb R^4$, not $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Metrically it would be fair to call this only a half plane.  ;-)

Comment: @TonyK, my phrasing is " a cylinder over the spiral" which amounts to a Cartesian product and is a subset of $\mathbb R^3.$ Similar to a "cone over the Clifford Torus" in $\mathbb R^4.$   http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2474.pdf

Comment: That's different from saying "The word for this object is 'cylinder'".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the shape you mean is given (up to similarity transformations) by the parametrisation
$$(u,v) \mapsto (\exp(\alpha u)\cos(u),\exp(\alpha u)\sin(u),v)$$
where $\alpha$ is some nonzero real number.
It is the Cartesian product of a logarithmic spiral with a straight line. I don't know if this shape has a name.